# Entering Germany after 3 months (having a residence permit) of absense and having received a UK's resince permit

Tags: uk, legal, germany, permits, work-permit

I'm not an EU citizen.

The situation is:

1. I lived in Germany for 3 years, still registered there and have a bank account
2. I have a German residence permit (niederlassungserlaubnis) received after a Blue Card
3. I got a job in the UK, went there and received UK's residence permit

I wasn't sure if I want to stay in the UK and now I want to go back to Germany.

**Am I eligible to go back to Germany having in mind that I was absent in Germany less than 6 months ?**

The law seems to be rather vague and it is specified that if intentions of staying abroad are not permanent then you may be able to return.